# How to support tableless columns with WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: css, drupal, wysiwyg, tableless

On the front page of a site I'm working on there's a small slideshow. It's not for pictures in particular, any content can go in, and I'm currently setting up the editing interface for the client. I'd like to be able to have one/two/more columns in the editable area, and ideally that would be via CSS - does anyone know of a WYSIWYG editor that supports this? I'm using Drupal (would prefer not to involve Panels as it would require a bit of work to make it a streamlined workflow for content entry) in case that matters to anyone.

To start the ball rolling, one way would be to use templates. I know CKEditor supports [templates](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Document/Templates), and [it looks like](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aPlugins/template) TinyMCE might have something similar. I don't know how well these work with tableless columns (the [CKEditor homepage demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) uses tables to achieve its two column effect).

Holding out for a cool solution!

Comment: +1, Awesome question I've often wondered. Personally, I abandoned WYSIWYG-ness in the editor because of this.

Comment: Looking forward to an answer to this, too.  I've tried DIV formatting as a means of replacing tables, and it feels like I keep coming back to the tables every time because I can predict how they'll behave better.

Comment: Do you mean the editable content spans multiple columns? Or do you just want a multi-columns layout in which one columns is editable?

Comment: @Litso I want the option to have the editable content be _n_ columns. This should be something that the user chooses, and should be mirrored in the WYSIWYG editor. I've updated the question slightly to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Ooh, tough one. I'll think about an answer, can't promise anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://www.aloha-editor.com/demos/3col/) shows an example of [the Aloha editor](http://www.aloha-editor.com/) working with CSS3 columns (and [this demo](http://www.aloha-editor.com/demos/css3/) is just plain nuts!). Very nice! I didn't see any way to create the columns through the editor, though that shouldn't be too difficult to add. There's already [a thread for Drupal integration](http://drupal.org/node/861392) as well. The editor also has a repository API which sounds very cool. It's at version 0.9.3, and I noticed the image plugin was still a work in progress, so I'm not sure it's ready for live use yet (I'm also interested in its compatibility). But very very interesting!

Comment: Brilliant. That editor is so much more than "an editor that can do columns"... I'm really looking forward to implementing this in a Drupal site and seeing a huge smile on my customer's face. Thanks for the tip, Andy!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah it's certainly more than just a columnful editor. It'd be nice to use Aloha for webmaster content editing (where you can require folk to have up-to-date browsers) on a project soonish.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [Columns Filter](http://drupal.org/project/columns_filter) module? On the input side, it may not be as wysiwyg as a solution with CKeditor templates, but I think it should work fine on the output side.

Comment: Lovely. Not exactly what I was looking for, but still looks v cool, thanks.